# Run WebTest in vNext build via PS-Remoting on Windows 10 server got "System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException"

Tags: powershell, tfs-2015, webtest, vnext

In TFS vNext build I deploy serveral webtests via PS-Remoting to one Windows 10 test agent and run all webtests. It does not not stable because sometimes I get an error with "System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException" (s.below)

Visual Studio 2015 has be installed on the server. The same tests under the sam condition run very well on Windows 7 test agent.

What is the reason and how could I fix this? Many thanks!

```
<Timestamp> [5] ERROR <MyService>.GlobalExceptionHandler:29 - Internal Server Error!
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GenerateHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean hostCanGenerate)
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Xml.XmlConfiguration.XmlReaderSection.get_ProhibitDefaultUrlResolver()
at System.Xml.Schema.Parser..ctor(SchemaType schemaType, XmlNameTable nameTable, SchemaNames schemaNames, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler)
at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.ComputeSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.CreateXmlReaderSettings()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, IList`1& schemaCollection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.LoadProviderManifest(XmlReader xmlReader, String location, Boolean checkForSystemNamespace, Schema& schema)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest.Load(XmlReader reader)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest..ctor(XmlReader reader)
at System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderManifest..ctor(String manifestToken)
at System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String versionHint)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Create()
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Create()   
at <MyService>.Persistence.EF.DeploymentRepository.CreateDeployment(String name, DeploymentStatus status)
at <MyService>.Persistence.EF.DeploymentRepository.CreateDeployment(String name)
at <MyService>.Controllers.DeploymentController.<CreateDeploymentAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Does this issue happened on other windows 10 machine? Only one project has this issue? Could you please share a sample project on OneDrive for me to has test?

Comment: Hi, yes, the issue only on Windows 10 agent not Windows 7. I have already checked events on the server and could not see any dependented-exceptions in system event-log. Best regards

Comment: It seems that the error is caused by your project not TFS build agent. Did you check the links that Andy posted below?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the links from reddit.com. Many thanks. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you installed the same version of VS on Windows 7 test agent? If not, you can try to remove VS from WIN10 and install that version same as WIN7, then try it again.

If the issue still exist, please check the Entity Framework version. Seems related to Entity Framework, see [this article](https://forums.asp.net/t/1987059.aspx?error%20the%20provider%20did%20not%20return%20a%20ProviderManifest%20instance) for more info, you can try using EFPowerTools to update Nuget EF accordingly.

Please reference below threads:

- [EntityFramework error: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551603/entityframework-error-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifest-instance)
- [How to use Entity Framework Power Tools in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999235/how-to-use-entity-framework-power-tools-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Hello Andy, yes, the same visual studio version on Windorws 10 and Windows 7 test agent. Best regards

Comment: @exquisitesilens Have you tried the EF upgrade? Seems not related TFS, It should be related to OS component, please refer to below link and check if that helps https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f7so7/catastrophic_failure_0x8000ffff_when_trying_to/,

Comment: Hi Andy, I have checked the user profile and deleted one strange user profile in registry. I hope it helps :) Best regards